# "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable" in Python pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe, typeerror, python-3.6

I imported pandas as pd.

```
>>>import pandas as pd
```

Assigned Series variables 'city_names' and 'population'

```
>>> city_names=pd.Series(['San Fransisco','San Jose','Sacromento'])
>>> population=pd.Series([8964,91598,034892])
```

Created DataFrame

```
>>> pd.DataFrame=({'City Name': city_names, 'Population':population})
```

While assigning DataFrame to the variable 'cities',

```
>>> cities=pd.DataFrame({'City Name ' : city_names, 'Population' : population})
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    cities=pd.DataFrame({'City Name ' : city_names, 'Population' : population})
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Also aware that 'dict' is a dictionary with (key,value) pairs! please let me know why this error occurs. I looked into other questions as well but could'nt find help.

Comment: Please also let me know how to access the 'cities' variable as a two dimensional array or list  if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code `pd.DataFrame=({'City Name': city_names, 'Population':population})` replaced `pd.DataFrame` function with a dictionary.

---

@Ankur please modify this edit to your liking.
PiR edit:

`pd.DataFrame` is a class defined by pandas. A class is "callable" meaning that you can call it with parentheses like so `pd.DataFrame()`. However, in Python the `=` is an assignment operator and you did `pd.DataFrame = {}` which assigned some dictionary to the same spot that the DataFrame class constructor used to be. You should not use that line specified by @Ankur. It will break your stuff every time.

Comment: I got it ; but the error is with 'cities' variable.

Comment: What you did was accidentally assigned a dictionary to the `DataFrame` attribute of the `pd` module.  Then when you tried to create a data frame by calling the data frame constructor `pd.DataFrame`, python found a dictionary instead of the constructor.  Whoops!

Comment: Yeah, coz before creating cities variable you have assigned a dictionary to pd.DataFrame. Restart your python repl and run your code again except don't run the line that I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Or use `import importlib; importlib.reload(pd)`

Comment: Did you mean that pd.DataFrame=({'City Name': city_names, 'Population':population}) and cities=pd.DataFrame({'City Name ' : city_names, 'Population' : population}) are assigned the same content? Excuse me I am new to Python.

Comment: Tried with import importlib and importlib.reload(pd). It worked fine. Does this mean the constructor is pointing to two same objects without over writing? Error has gone. Please let me know if I understood correctly.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame` is a class defined by `pandas`.  A class is "callable" meaning that you can call it with parentheses like so `pd.DataFrame()`.  However, in Python the `=` is an assignment operator and you did `pd.DataFrame = {}` which assigned some dictionary to the same spot that the DataFrame class constructor used to be.  You should **not** use that line specified by @Ankur.  It will break your stuff every time.

Comment: @piRSquared - Maybe the best is add this comments to answer, because very valuable, what do you think? Is possible edit `Ankur` answer?

Comment: @piRSquared, got it. Thank you.